# Which datatype is used for 10^500 in c language

Tags: c

Problem Statement
Addition is a very basic operation in mathematics. Jimmy was very weak in addition, so his father decided to teach him. Jimmy is given a number and has to perform addition on all the digits of that number till that the large number gets converted into a single digit. Your task is to prepare a program for him so that he can easily find out the final number.
Input Format
First line contains T (1<=T<=100) the number of test cases.
Each test case contains integer N (1<=N<=10^100).

Output Format
For each test case, output the one digit number by repeatedly adding the digits.
Constraints
1<=T<=100
1<=N<=10^500

Comment: You need to show an attempt and ask us a specific question where you were stuck or where you are having issues. Copy/pasting an assignment will lead to a very fast close question.

Comment: Hint: You don't need to store the entire string of digits as one number.

Comment: You might have [linked the question](http://codingheaven.org/index.php/programs/beginner/one-digit-answer/statement)

Comment: For inputting `10^100` See [google](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googol)

Comment: just tell me the meaning of 10^500

Comment: `10^500` means (in this context) `10 raised to power 500`. But the question [(see my link)](http://codingheaven.org/index.php/programs/beginner/one-digit-answer/statement) has a typo. It says the upper range of `n` is `10^100` and also is `10^500`. But that's the number of digits in the decimal input string (perhaps +1, or +2 for a `'0'` string terminator, or +3 to include a `newline`). But the huge number need not concern you. If you study the test cases, you can see you must examine each digit and reduce their sum to a single digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd represent the very large input number as `char`, and the total of the digits (first pass) will easily fit in an `int`.  You'll need a little more than simple arithmetic, but it shouldn't be difficult (`case` seems a likely way to manage the job).

Comment: "Each test case contains integer N (1<=N<=10^100)." -->   `unsigned long` will not represent `10^100`.

Comment: @chux No, but it will easily represent the sum of 100 single digit integers, which can't exceed 900.  Actually, a common signed integer would, even in 16-bit days.

Comment: @ZeissIkon did you even study [the original question](http://codingheaven.org/index.php/programs/beginner/one-digit-answer/statement) and its sample test cases?

Comment: @WeatherVane There are up to 100 test cases; each contains an integer up to 100 digits (though the constraint is given as 10^500).  First pass, done with a string represenation of the input, will give a value up to either 900 or 4500 -- both are smaller than a 16-bit compiler's `int` limit.  Additional passes will be required to reduce the first-pass figure to successively smaller values and get a one-digit final result for each test case.  I pointed to the place to start; that's all I'm going to give for a homework assignment.

Comment: @ZeissIkon that's absurdly complicated. Additional passes?

Comment: @WeatherVane On the other hand, it's within the programming abilities of any first-semester C student.  BTW, if the digits of a test case sum to 10 or more, you have to re-sum the digits if you're to get a one-digit output for each test case..  Otherwise, a test case of 12345 wouldn't give one digit (sums to 15) -- you have to make another pass to get 6.

Comment: I see now with the clarity of your answer and comments.  Hopefully it was what OP asked - that was a bit unclear.

Comment: Thats a simple cross-sum calculation. I just would use two approaches: one to fold the input to an integer and the second operating on integers only.

Comment: I'm a fairly competent jackleg programmer; I'm nothing like a mathematician.  Simple concept, easy to debug, makes for happy first-year students and happy teachers.

Comment: OOh OOh mybad I misread the question to be a simple modulus of the digit sum. Apologies for negative comments.